# Removing Bokeh Icon from figures embedded in Jupyter?

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm making some notebooks in Jupyter, and I decided to use Bokeh for creating interactive plots. Two things that really bug me are the icons printed in the top-left corner of the plots, and the icons printed after running `output_notebook()`. I'd like to remove these to help minimize visual clutter.

Here's a simple script that can be run in Jupyter demonstrating my issue:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *
output_notebook()

N = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

p1 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS)

p1.circle(x, y, legend="sin(x)")
p1.circle(x, 2*y, legend="2*sin(x)", color="orange", )
p1.circle(x, 3*y, legend="3*sin(x)", color="green", )

show(p1)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKicf.png) is the output from this code on my machine.

Comment: Can you show us some code towards removing the icons?

Comment: While it is easily possible to disable either or both (see below), leaving the project logo intact in published artifacts (so that users who may not know about Bokeh but wish to learn more by simply clicking on it) is a considerate way to acknowledge value of a project that is made available to everyone for free.

Answer (score 7):

The answers to your questions (use `output_notebook(..., hide_banner=True)` and `plot.logo=None`) are available in the documentation:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/resources_embedding.html#bokeh.io.output_notebook

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot.logo